# I am replacing my Spring boot camel rest api to AWS Lambda. I am getting NullPointerException

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-aws

In local while testing it running properly but during Lamda testing getting below error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
> at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.setupOutInterceptorChain(AbstractClient.java:937) ~[task/:na]
> at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.createMessage(AbstractClient.java:1014) ~[task/:na]
> at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.finalizeMessage(WebClient.java:1111) ~[task/:na]
> at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doChainedInvocation(WebClient.java:1084) ~[task/:na]
> at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:932) ~[task/:na]
> at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:901) ~[task/:na]
> at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.invoke(WebClient.java:364) ~[task/:na]
> at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.CxfRsProducer.invokeHttpClient(CxfRsProducer.java:348) ~[task/:na]
> at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.CxfRsProducer.process(CxfRsProducer.java:102) ~[task/:na]
> at org.apache.camel.support.SynchronousDelegateProducer.process(SynchronousDelegateProducer.java:48) ~[task/:na]
> at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:66) ~[task/:na]
> at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.doRun(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:818) ~[task/:na]
> at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:726) ~[task/:na]
> ... 31 common frames omitted
> [2m2023-05-16 16:09:08.913[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m8[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Failed delivery for (MessageId: 366BDD4716C614A-0000000000000002 on ExchangeId: 366BDD4716C614A-0000000000000002). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.NullPointerException. Processed by failure processor: FatalFallbackErrorHandler[null]

How to resolve NullPointerException here?
Is this because of any camel configuration to be set for AWS Labda?

Comment: https://cxf.apache.org/docs/bundling-cxf-into-single-jar-with-maven-shade-plugin.html. Check if adding the shade plugin works or not.

Comment: The issue got resolved by adding below:

Comment: <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">                               <mainClass>Application</mainClass>
 </transformer>
 <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
  <resource>META-INF/cxf/bus-extensions.txt</resource>
   </transformer>
</transformers>